# Powershell Executed from Path with Space Produces No Output

Tags: powershell

From within Powershell and Powershell ISE, Powershell scripts that exist in locations with a space in the path do not execute, or at least their output is not shown in the command window.

I have a Powershell script (`helloworld.ps1`) that contains only the following code:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

If the script is executed from:

```
"C:\Temp\helloworld.ps1"
```

The output is: `Hello World`

If the script is executed from:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\helloworld.ps1"
```

The output is blank.

Note that the path is surrounded with quotes when executed (otherwise, obviously, I would have errors). I've duplicated this same problem on multiple machines in multiple environments, so it doesn't seem to be a configuration issue.

**For what reason is Powershell output hidden if the script itself is executed from a path that contains a space**?

Comment: `C:>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\helloworld.ps1"` should print: `C:\Users\e313681\Desktop\Scripts\ps1\test\hello.ps1` according to my test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do this:

```
"C:\Temp\helloworld.ps1"
```

That's a quoted string and PowerShell will simply output it.

If you want to *execute* a quoted string as a command, you need the `&` (call or invocation) operator:

```
& "C:\Temp\helloworld.ps1"
```

Otherwise you can write it without the quotes and PowerShell will understand that it's a command:

```
C:\Temp\helloworld.ps1
```

If the script's path or filename contains a space and you want to run it, you have to use `&` and quote the path and filename.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a file, put its path without any quotes around it:

```
PS C:\> C:\Temp\helloworld.ps1
```

If the path has spaces in it, **escape spaces using a back-tick** (`):

```
PS C:\> C:\Program` Files\Microsoft` Office\helloworld.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as a quote isn't the first character, it will work.

```
C":\Program Files\Microsoft Office\helloworld.ps1"

Hello World
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a `.` before the path

```
C:>. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\helloworld.ps1"
```

Comment: Why dot-sourcing the script with `.` instead of using the call operator `&`?

Comment: @ManuelBatsching You can use either in this case. See this answer for clarification https://stackoverflow.com/a/11891748/5361412

Comment: Dot-sourcing affects scope. Don't dot-source unless you understand what it does.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, as that does seem to work. I'm still unsure as to why this behavior is as it is. EDIT: Bill_Steward explained why the `.` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Beems `.` will pull any variables or function defs into the current session scope. I honestly use it more often than `&` because *I want any function or variable I define in the script to be available outside the script*

Comment: That's useful for a profile script but not other scripts. Scope exists for a reason. Usually you want to create a module if you want to export functions.